# How to connect MySQL database with objective-c project?

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c

How to connect MySQl database with my iphone application, to read, write, save some data into the database?

Answer (score 1):

There's a wrapper at http://code.google.com/p/mysql-cocoa-framework/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19185019)

Comment: Point taken, but in this case even the essential parts of the answer are the size of a non-trivial software project, which is what I've linked to.