# Objective-c How to connect with MySQL

Tags: mysql, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i connect MySQL database with objective project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915170/how-can-i-connect-mysql-database-with-objective-project)

How can I connect to a database in objective-c? What options are there and what is the best one?

Comment: This question has been asked multiple times. Take a look at the sidebar to the right of this page.

Answer (score -2):

Sadly you can't connect to a specific DBMS, if what you need is to retrieve data from a MySQL database, you can use connections to it and get the information you need, obviously with web services set on the server side. If you need a DBMS for iPhone, there is SQLite or native CoreData which is your best option for data management.

Comment: Completely wrong. MySQL provides a C library. So you can use it right away from Objective-C, or create a object-oriented wrapper, using Objective-C classes.